# How to write regex which matches all characters that does not contain any control characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to write a regex that would match for words that do not contain any control characters. I read that negative lookahead are used for that and wrote this regex:

```
/(?!\p{C}+)/
```

But don't get why it's not working. Expected result:

`word without control characters` - match

`word with control character ‎between` - don't match

Comment: Can you post an example of `word with control character ‎between`?

Comment: Control character is after the word `character`. If you'd paste it in some kind of regex tool, it would show you `‎‎U+200E` in that place.

Comment: Are you wanting to match either the full line or not the line at all, in case there's a control character in the line?

Comment: Yes, full line or not a line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any control char using `\p{C}`. You can match any char other than a control char using `\P{C}`. See a [regex demo with your string](https://regex101.com/r/ntL2gd/1).

If you want to match words not glued to some control char, use `(?<!\p{C})\b\w+\b(?!\p{C})`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntL2gd/2). Here, `(?<!\p{C})` is a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with a control char, `\b\w+\b` matches one or more word chars within word boundaries and `(?!\p{C})`  is a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with a control char.

If you want to "exclude" CR and LF chars from the `\p{C}` pattern you can use `(?<![^\P{C}\r\n])\b\w+\b(?![^\P{C}\r\n])`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntL2gd/3).